# Message font garbled in Apple Mail in Sierra 10.12.5

Tags: mail.app, font

One of our Macs is having issues displaying message text in Mail. At startup, the messages appear normally for a short while, then suddenly "flip" to display all the text as boxes containing question marks. I was able to watch it happen, then retrieved the following line from the system log stamped at the same time:

Jun  2 14:04:22 dyn-144-92-105-238 com.apple.PerformanceAnalysis.animationperfd[252]: BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[EVFILT_MACHPORT] monitored resource vanished before the source cancel handler was invoked

Does this mean anythng to anyone? For what it's worth, it seems to mostly  affect email coming from PCs, rarely Macs.

Should also add that I discovered and was able to remove a corrupted, non-essential system font from the machine in question, but that didn't help.

Comment: What is your message font set to in mail/preferences?

Comment: If you do view/message/raw source on a message where this has happened, do you see HTML code giving a name for the font being requested for displaying the text?